# Javascript: SHA512 value convert to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework

I already crypt the variable '`getShaValue`' to sha512. Then combine it with many variable like 'name','ic' using `JSON.stringify`. But when I debug my JSON object, the value of SHA512 didn't show the right value. If I only debug the value before convert it into JSON, it show the right value.

Here is my function to crypt the value

```
  self.sha512 = function () {
    var value = self.generateSHAvalue();
    var getShaValue= CryptoJS.SHA512(value);
    return getShaValue;
};
```

I combine it with many variable

```
var authToken = SHA.sha512();
var requestData = JSON.stringify({
   name: "Test", 
   authToken: authToken
})
console.log("requestData: " + JSON.stringify(requestData));
```

The result of the console is

```
{
   "name": "Test",
   "authToken": '"$super":{"$super":{}},"words":[1157899753,2720090447,1588426441,2244605341,2288345873,3771352114,2976397435,3171064119,-130018106,2601059156,3822838925,2519334849,1988499628,2785343384,-556559616,-1270654637],"sigBytes":64'
}
```

But it should be like this:

```
{
   "name": "Test",
   "authToken": "21507C7061D3F45058A95751E2FB332DD68F6A2ADC2039DE4341199643E12ADEFB8DF603C3F 34E71FB447F46B82BC5DC7BD2B81B83B389D8950583BEFB424676"
}
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included the binary digest in the json. Try converting it to hex first:

```
self.sha512 = function () {
  var value = self.generateSHAvalue();
  var shaHex = CryptoJS.SHA512(value).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
  return shaHex ;
};
```